# Twig tag include vs function include

Tags: php, twig

Twig's documentation for [tag include](http://twig.symfony.com/doc/tags/include.html) looks very similar to that of [function include](http://twig.symfony.com/doc/functions/include.html).

Tag include:

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
```

Function include:

```
{{ include('template.html') }}
```

Can somebody point out in what circumstances, one is preferred over the other? Thanks!

Comment: It's a wild guess, but seems to me, that second option should take less processing times, due to easier/faster tokenization. But it's a guess.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`{{ include() }}` Was introduce in Symfony 2.2:

Using a function allows you to do whatever you want with the output (which is not possible with a tag), like a simple:

```
{{ set content = include('some_template') }}
```

But as Fabien Potentier (twig founder) said

> the function and the tag does indeed the exact same thing

You can find the discution about it's introduction here: https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/926

Answer (score 1):

Twig 3.x documentation for the [include tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/include.html) now states:

> It is recommended to use the include function instead as it provides the same features with a bit more flexibility:
>
> - The include function is semantically more “correct” (including a template outputs its rendered contents in the current scope; a tag should not display anything);
> - The include function is more “composable”:
> - The include function does not impose any specific order for arguments thanks to named arguments.