# What's the difference between the include tag and the include function?

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

I saw someone including a template on his application using the twig template system.
He included his template like this:

```
{{ include( 'Bundlename:Directory:template.html.twig' ) }}
```

instead of this:

```
{% include 'Bundlename:Directory:template.html.twig' %}
```

At first I thought he was using a custom twig extension, but it actually 
works on symfony in general, even though its not documented.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

So is there a difference between the two? 
why is it not documented? 
if the syntax is wrong why is it even working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is documented http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/include.html.

[Twig tag include vs function include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566167/twig-tag-include-vs-function-include)

Comment: So according to Fabien potentier (twig founder)  the function and the tag does indeed the exact same thing. 
Don't get why both variants exist, but thanks clarifying

Comment: I assume the tag was kept for BC.

Comment: Here is discussion about include function [https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/926](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/926). Link from referenced so question is no longer valid.